# HDFS performance for small files

Tags: performance, hadoop, io, hdfs

I'm new to Hadoop. Recently I'm trying to process (only read) many **small** files on hdfs/hadoop. The average file size is about **1 kb** and the number of files is more than 10M. The program must be written in C++ due to some limitations.

This is just a performance evaluation so I only use 5 machines for data nodes. Each of the data node have 5 data disks.

I wrote a small **C++ project to read the files directly from hard disk**(not from HDFS) to build the performance base line. The program will create 4 reading threads for each disk. The performance result is to have about 14MB/s per disk. Total throughput is about 14MB/s * 5 * 5 = **350MB**/s (14MB/s * 5 disks * 5 machines ).

However, when this program ( still using C++, dynamically linked to libhdfs.so, creating 4*5*5=100 threads) **reads files from hdfs** cluster, the throughput is about only **55MB/s**.

If this programming is triggered in mapreduce (hadoop streamming, 5 jobs, each have 20 threads, total number of threads is still 100), the throughput goes down to about 45MB/s. (I guess it's slow down by some bookkeeping process).

I'm wondering what is the reasonable performance HDFS can prvoide. As you can see, comparing with native code, the data throughput is only about **1/7**. Is it the problem of my config? Or HDFS limitation? Or Java limitation? What's the best way for my scenario? Will sequence file help (much)? What is the reasonable throughput comparing to native IO read we can expect?

Here's some of my config:

NameNode heap size 32G.

Job/Task node heap size 8G.

NameNode Handler Count: 128

DataNode Handler Count: 8

DataNode Maximum Number of Transfer Threads: 4096

1GBps ethernet.

Thanks.

Comment: Supplemental: The program read a file list from stdin, which contains millions of file paths.

Comment: I always forget the "why's" and "how's," but try making your input files at least as large as the block size (default 64 MB) and then re-run your profiling.  The way you combine your files depends on their format; like you can just concatenate them if they're simply text.

Comment: I know that merge the files into bigger files can significantly improve the performance but this won't be our first choice.
BTW, reading files directly from disk will have much improvement, too.
I really like to know what's the reasonable throughput HDFS can provide comparing to native access. 1/7 doesn't seem good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try to understand our limits and see when we hit them 
a) We need namenode to give us information where files are sitting.  I can assume that this number is around thousands per second. More information is here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-2149
Assuming this number to be 10000K we should be able to get information about 10 MB second for 1K files. (somehow you get more...). may 
b) Overhead of HDFS. This overhead is mostly on latency not in throughput. HDFS can be tuned to serve a lot of files in parralel. HBase is doing it and we can take settings from HBase tuning guides. The question here is actually how much Datanodes you need
c) Your LAN. You move data from the network so you might hit 1GB ethernet throughput limit. (i think it what you got.

I also have to agree with Joe - that HDFS is not built for the scenario and you should use other technology (like HBase, if you like Hadoop stack) or compress files together - for example into sequence files.

Regarding reading bigger files from HDFS - run DFSIO benchmark and it will be your number. 
In the same time - SSD on single host perfectly can be a solution also.

Comment: The reason I can have better namenode performance is because I'm using better hardware. Dell R620, 2 E5-2650 CPU ( total 32 cores including hyperthread), 128GB RAM.

Comment: I don't think I hit the limitation of 1GB ethernet because the total throughput is achieved by 5 machines. The 5 data nodes are connected by 1GB eithernet switch. Since the switch and eithernet adapter are both full duplex, I should get at least 2.5GB bandwidth for 5 machines.

Comment: So I think you hit botlneck from overhead of set up file transfer from the Datanode (or indeed NameNode bottleneck

Comment: @DavidGruzman : Would it be beneficial to increase the no. of dfs.datanode.max.xcievers and dfs.namenode.handler.count, as the NN looks powerful??

Comment: It will increase concurrency that datanode can handle. In the same time - it will not decrease per-file-read overhead. In the same time -I would seriously consider for example HBASE or some other solution suited for small data chunks.

Comment: Will compressing files into sequence files make it slower to access them? Like say if you use hadoop for storing images for a web application. Will it become slower?

Comment: it will slower random access. But if you need random access - HDFS is not best solution...

Answer (score 9):

HDFS is really not designed for many small files.

For each new file you read, the client has to talk to the namenode, which gives it the location(s) of the block(s) of the file, and then the client streams the data from the datanode.

Now, in the best case, the client does this once, and then finds that it *is* the machine with the data on it, and can read it directly from disk. This will be fast: comparable to direct disk reads.

If it's not the machine that has the data on it, then it must stream the data over the network. Then you are bound by network I/O speeds, which shouldn't be terrible, but still a bit slower than direct disk read.

However, you're getting an even worse case- where the overhead of talking to the namenode becomes significant. With only 1KB files, you are getting to the point where you're exchanging just as much metadata as actual data. The client has to make two separate network exchanges to get the data from each file. Add to this that the namenode is probably getting hammered by all of these different threads and so it might become a bottleneck.

So to answer your question, yes, if you use HDFS for something it's not designed to be used for, it's going to be slow. Merge your small files, and use MapReduce to get data locality, and you'll have much better performance. In fact, because you'll be able to take better advantage of sequential disk reads, I wouldn't be surprised if reading from one big HDFS file was even *faster* than reading many small local files.

Comment: I'm considering to merge small files. But normal I don't need to read all of them. For example, I have 100M files but I only need to read 30M of the files. Will sequence file work work for this? Since I need to load data into C++ program, I'll use hadoop streaming. Can sequence file work in this case? Do I have better options?

BTW, my scenario is that I already have 100M files, and will add 10s of hundereds of files every day, remove less then 100 files every day, and no files will be modified.

Comment: I agree to Joe that I should merge the small files into bigger files. Looks like I should figure out how to do this with hadoop streaming. 
And find out if sequence file or HAR will fulfill my requirements.

Answer (score 3):

just to add to whatever Joe has said, another difference between HDFS and other filesystems is that it keeps disk i/o as less as possible by storing data in larger blocks (normally 64M or 128M) as compared to traditional FS where FS block size is in the order of KBs. for that reason they always say that HDFS is good at processing few large files rather than large no of small files. the reason behind this is the fact that, although there have been significant advancements in components like cpu, ram etc in recent times, the disk i/o is an area where we are still not that much advance. this was the intention behind having so huge blocks(unlike traditional FS) and keep the usage of disk as less as possible.

moreover if the block size is too small, we will have a greater no of blocks. which means more metadata. this may again degrade the performance, as more amount of information needs to loaded into the memory. for each block, which is considered an object in HDFS has about 200B of metadata associated with it. if you have many small blocks, it'll just increase the metadata and you might end up with RAM issues.

There is very good post on Cloudera's blog section which talks about the same issue. You can visit that [here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/).

Comment: Hi I am sorry for barging in like this but could you please tell me if hadoop could be used to serve images for a website with a significant amount of traffic? Does merging many small files into one big file (the sequence file) make it slower to access. Much thanks in advance.

Comment: Your'e welcome @qualebs..This doesn't sound a very feasible idea. Hadoop all by itself(HDFS to be specific), like any other FS, is not suitable for use cases which demand real time access to the stored data, like a website wherein users would post a query and expect instantaneous response.

Comment: What alternatives do I have for storing such small files in a distributed way i.e limitless space? and also for fast access?